# How to stop re-render of Component on route change(usually on going back to history)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

If my app goes from `"/profile/1"` to `"/company/1"` and then I go back to `"/profile/1"`, the page should not fetch the data again.

Router config:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />
  <Route path="/company/:id" component={Company} />
</Switch>
```

Profile component

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUserProfile(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
      console.log("fetching profile again");
      this.fetchUserProfile(this.props.match.params.id);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Link to={"/company/1"}>company</Link>
  }
}
```

How do I stop `Profile` from re-fetching the api? `componentDidUpdate` doesn't help here.

Comment: Where is your data stored e.g. state, redux, ..?

Comment: For `Profile.js`, it's in state

Comment: Are you using any state container like redux?

Comment: @XPD yes, but not for data of Profile.js

Comment: You can use a global variable to store it. You can use a closure to hide it from direct manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

You could cache the data in something like `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`, or you could use *redux*.

You can read more about `sessionStorage` here: [MDN Web Docs on sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Then in your `componentDidMount` you can check if the data already exits in your cache, and only fetch if it does not.

Here is an example of what your `componentDidMount` could look like if you use `sessionStorage`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let data = sessionStorage.getItem('profileData');       //Get the data from sessionStorage
    if(data) {
        this.setState({profile: data})                      // Used cached data
    }
    else {
        this.fetchUserProfile(this.props.match.params.id);  // Fetch data
    }
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that there's a storage limitation on browser for session and local storage. Also they are visible to users if not encrypted. So if you have sensitive data you might need some additional security.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on previous answers, here's a totally different take that you can use. Using the React Context API to store the data once it's loaded.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Using context you can easily store the data and check if the data is already loaded when the compoennt is re-rendered. Here's a quick runnable example, as you can see _fetch is only fired on the first render.

```js
const Context = React.createContext({});

// Home
const Home = () => {
  return <div>Homepage</div>;
};

// Profile
const Profile = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(Context);

  const _fetch = () => {
    console.log("fetching... it only fetches it once");
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve({ message: "ok!" }));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!context.cache) {
      _fetch().then(data => context.setCache(data));
    }
  }, [context]);

  return context.cache ? <div>{context.cache.message}</div> : <div>...</div>;
};

// App
function App() {
  const [cache, setCache] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ cache, setCache }}>
      <div className="App">
        <ReactRouterDOM.MemoryRouter>
          <ul>
            <ReactRouterDOM.Link to="/">
              <li>Home</li>
            </ReactRouterDOM.Link>
            <ReactRouterDOM.Link to="/profile">
              <li>Profile</li>
            </ReactRouterDOM.Link>
          </ul>
          <ReactRouterDOM.Switch>
            <ReactRouterDOM.Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
            <ReactRouterDOM.Route exact={true} path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          </ReactRouterDOM.Switch>
        </ReactRouterDOM.MemoryRouter>
      </div>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.1.2/react-router-dom.min.js" integrity="sha256-Ga/RV3YJI+cd1/ML8yitEoluFHUJZ7HTH90az8fOFZU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```